# Set percentage width recording to parent stack, whose width depends on other child

Tags: flutter

I am having a `Stack` with two child elements. The second element is some `Text` and the first element is a `Container` with some blue background color. I want to have the height of the `Container` match the height of the `Stack` given by the height of the `Text`-Widget. And the width of my `Container` should be set dynamically with a percentage of the width of the `Stack` which also comes from the `Text` widget.

**In other words:** I want to build a progress indicator, that I can set dynamically. Altough the width of my parent is not known before build-time. And this width should be givene by the text-child-widget.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 20,
        color: const Color(0xffa0a4fc),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
      child: Text(
        "some text",
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 22,
        ),
      ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: check `FractionallySizedBox`

Comment: @pskink I tried doing it with that. But I could not get it to work inside my Stack. Because my Stack has no clear width.

Comment: the container doesnt have any child, which is why it wont take the size of the text. Is there a reason why you cant have the text as a child for the container? do you have better examples maybe?

Comment: @Texv The text should be able to be longer than the container, so I am not using it as the child of the container. Also the text should not determine the width of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [`Stack` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html):

> Each child of a Stack widget is either positioned or non-positioned (...). The stack sizes itself to contain all the non-positioned children, (...). The positioned children are then placed relative to the stack according to their top, right, bottom, and left properties.

So, using `FractionallySizedBox` inside `Positioned` and then having the `Text` determine the `Stack` size would do the trick:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        widthFactor: factor,
        child: ...,
      ),
    ),
    Text(...),
  ],
)
```

See a [demo on dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?id=73cf9b5bdbd649cc07a8ae45038f5e77)

Using a `TextPainter` to calculate size of `Stack`'s contents is also correct solution for your case but it has some drawbacks:

- It won't work for more advanced cases where the content of the loader is something other than just single `Text` (as in the demo above).
- It's slightly less performant because it needs to calculate `Text`'s size twice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you need to calculate text width :

```
final TextPainter myTextPainter = TextPainter(
      text:
          TextSpan(text: myText, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, minWidth: 0.0);

    final myTextSize = myTextPainter.size;
```

full code for your reference :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  String myText = 'loading.. please wait';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextPainter myTextPainter = TextPainter(
      text:
          TextSpan(text: myText, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, minWidth: 0.0);

    final myTextSize = myTextPainter.size;

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (!_animationController.isAnimating) {
                setState(() {
                  myText = 'loading.. please wait';
                });
                _animationController.reset();
                _animationController.forward().then((value) {
                  setState(() {
                    myText = 'loading.. completed';
                  });
                });
              }
            },
            child: const Text("Start Animating")),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.loose,
              children: [
                AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _animationController,
                    builder: (context, _) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        height: myTextSize.height,
                        width: (_animationController.value * myTextSize.width),
                      );
                    }),
                Text(
                  myText,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```